# CSS: Unordered List Styling

Tags: css, html-lists

I need to create a CSS class that will allow me to list all the ingredients in a recipe. Here are the specifications for the unordered list:

- Left indent
- No bullet or other icon
- No space between heading (H2) and first item in list
- No space between items in list
- Space after last item in list

I need to do this without effecting the regular paragraphs, regular unordered lists, or other settings.

Good at HTML; poor at CSS, so explicit directions would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

CSS works by priority and identifiers. To target all H2 elements on a page, you would declare

```
h2 {
 color: #00FF00;
}
```

However, you can also get more specific and target only H2 elements within a DIV for instance:

```
div h2 {
 color: #00FF00;
}
```

Along with targeting just the elements, you can use either an ID or CLASS name to help the targeting. Use the # symbols to target IDs and the . to target CLASSES

HTML

```
<div id="ingredients">
<h2>Heading</h2>
<ul>
<li class="selected">Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    #ingredients {
    margin: 0em;
    margin-left: 1em;
    }    

    #ingredients h2 {
         color: #00FF00;
    margin-bottom: 0em;
        }

   #ingredients ul {
    margin-bottom: 2em;
   }
    #ingredients ul li {
     list-style: none;
     margin: 0em .5em;
     color: #00FFFF;
    }
    #ingredients ul li .selected {
     color: #FFFF00;
    }
```

Finally, CSS also has importance in the order of declaration, consider the following

```
h1 {
font-size: 2em;
font-color: #000000;
}

h1 {
font-color: #FF0000;
}
```

In this case, the H1 color will be red due to the fact the second H1 declaration overwrites the previous one. Just s note to remember.
}

Comment: Thank you for the help and detailed explanation. Helped me understand what's going on here. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
h2 {
    margin-bottom: 0;   // eliminate distance from headline, applies to all h2s though
}
ul {
    padding: 0 0 0 1em; // left indent, no other padding
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;  // space on bottom, maybe use a bottom-padding instead
}
ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```